# Xamarin Forms using Xamarin iOS today extension

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

With Xamarin.iOS, you can create a 'Today extension' which is basically just a widget that the user sees on their 'Today' screen. Microsoft have created a tutorial on creating one of these extensions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions).  In essence it is simply just a UIViewController displayed by the OS.

I've thought of two ways this could possibly be done. Either creating a widget with Xamarin.iOS (I'd need a way of 'importing' it, if anyone knows if that could be done?) or creating it with Xamarin Forms, but I don't know if this is possible or if I'm just missing something?

I'm looking for somebody to point me in the right direction

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I haven't tried anything code wise, as I wouldn't have any idea where to start